# Como acesso um site local seguro pelo firefox?

Tags: apache, servidor, firefox, https, localhost

Eu estou querendo liberar um site que estou desenvolvendo pelo navegador Chrome e preciso corrigir os bugs de CSS que estão ocorrendo no Firefox. Porém estou tendo dificuldades em acessá-lo pelo Firefox.

Mensagem no Firefox:

> **Não Conectou:** Potencial Problema de Segurança
>
> O Firefox detectou uma potencial ameaça de segurança e não prosseguiu para local.meusite.com.br porque este site exige uma conexão segura.

Seria um endereço local, exemplo:
https://local.meusite.com.br:8810/

Sites comprovam sua identidade através de certificados. O Firefox não confia neste site porque ele usa um certificado que não é válido para local.meusite.com.br:8810. O certificado só é válido para .

Código do erro: MOZILLA_PKIX_ERROR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT

Ao clicar neste código, o Firefoz aponta para:

```
O certificado não é considerado confiável porque é autoassinado.

HTTP Strict Transport Security: true
Chave HTTP pública fixa: false

Cadeia de certificados:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBjCCAe4CCQCir/8eGDIE/jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBFMQswCQYDVQQGEw
...etc (removi o restante por não ser pertinente à pergunta)...
3+56a5njSTFYKw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

No `Google Chrome` eu consigo liberar, mesmo ele dando uma mensagem de restrição, mas como faço para acessar no Firefox, um site seguro no local?

Não tem a opção de continuar assim mesmo...

**Tutorial que segui para gerar o certificado:**

```
Criando um Certificado SSL
$ cd ~

Crie a chave privada (é requerido duas vezes uma senha)
$ openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024

Crie a assinatura desta chave com uma requisição do certificado (mesma senha criada acima)
$ openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr

Preencha os dados conforme exemplo
Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]: BR
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]: SP
Locality Name (eg, city) []: Sao_Paulo
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]: Empresa XYZ
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []: Development
Common Name (eg, YOUR name) []: local.meusite.com.br
Email Address []: (seu_email)@meusite.com.br
A challenge password []: # (deixe em branco)
An optional company name []: # (deixe em branco)

Criando o certificado
$ openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt

Remova a senha do server key
$ cp server.key server.tmp
$ openssl rsa -in server.tmp -out server.key

Mova o certificado para a pasta de configuração do apache do MAMP
$ cp server.crt /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache
$ cp server.key /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache

Abra /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf e descomente a linha:
Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-ssl.conf.
```

Comment: Não entendi, porque negativaram a pergunta, ela é pertinente a minha necessidade de corrigir problemas de programação?

Comment: Tira o https e acessa so por http... ja tentou?

Comment: Caro Ivan, ao invés de usar "invalido" você tentou usar o **mkcert** (https://blog.filippo.io/mkcert-valid-https-certificates-for-localhost/)? Vale lembrar que tem que tirar o seu outro certificado, se não você vai conflitar as coisas, eu não testei, mas parece que é suportado por MacOS, Windows e algumas distros Linux, veja se lhe ajuda. Só pra constar, não deu pra entender bem sua pergunta, se é sobre o certificado de fato, ou se é sobre como adicionar certificado inválidos "nas exceções do Firefox", porque se for o caso do segundo ai a pergunta seria de fato off-topic.

Comment: @Andre provavelmente ele quer simular o ambiente HTTPS justamente para testes, HTTP com certeza ele consegue, a questão é testar o ambiente e provavelmente redirecionamentos e até outros programas de terceiros que EXIGEM que o site seja em HTTPS, portanto acessar em HTTP não vai resolver o problema do Ivan.

Comment: E como eu removo o outro? Vou adicionar a pergunta o processo que eu fiz o certificado.

Comment: Acho que [encontrei](http://lists.gno.org/cert-maint-mac-10.5.8/)

Comment: Então, @GuilhermeNascimento, eu criei o certificado usando esse mkcert, mas continua dando o mesmo problema com um certificado diferente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui aqui fazendo o seguinte:

Primeiro cliquei no ícone de cadeado do navegador e fui para as configurações do Firefox:

**Preferências > Privacidade e segurança > Certificados**

na URL: `about:preferences#privacy`

Depois cliquei em "Ver Certificados...", importei o certificado pelo arquivo: `meusite.com.br.crt`e fiz um check nas duas opções que aparecem... depois apareceu o botão que permite abrir o site correndo os riscos.

Comment: Eu tentando perceber o porque que a pergunta teve uma votação negativa, acredito bastante que isto ajudará mais pessoas no futuro

Comment: @Medium acredito q a propria resposta defina isto, não posso falar por quem negativou, mas votei para fechar, porque a propria resposta do Ivan confirmou, a pergunta é off-topic, eu também gostaria muito de fazer diversas perguntas no site, perguntas sobre Benchmark, Cluster e estratégias voltadas para estruturação de aplicações e banco, mas assuntos benchmark, clusters e "estratégias" são off-topic ou baseadas em opinião, e as regras do site são claras sobre o que é escopo aceito e o que não é, e por isso respeito as regras.